# Can you find firmware for my Best TW-520 Wireless Access Point?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, firmware

I bought an access point, one month later I reset it and I can't change the default settings.

If reset the same settings stay. I tried searching for firmware but I couldn't find any.

It's name is: Best TW-520 from tasco
Product info: http://www.tasco.com.cn/showpro.asp?id=222

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet will be to contact the [manufacturer](http://www.telewins.com) and ask them for firmware

Their website might have links, but it is a bit broken so it is hard to be sure.  They have email and skype contact details however.